# Extract csrf value from html with cheerio

Tags: java, jquery, postman, cheerio

Goal : 
1. Extract `csrf` value from my GET request response body
2. Store extracted 'csrf' value in environment variable
3. Use it in subsequent POST request.

Found a Solution and working: 
var matchSETTINGS cheerio.load(responseBody);
Extract `var matchSETTINGS = text.match(var a= (.*););`

Comment: Your response body is not a valid `JSON`. Those are `DOM` elements

Answer (score 0):

This is bit complicated, but achievable using various ways. Here I'm showing you a static way, change it as per your requirement.

Postman supports [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) library, that you can use to parse HTML responses.

```
var html = cheerio(responseBody);

//get script tag data
var htmlData = html[14].children[1].children[5].children[0].data;

var csrfIndex = htmlData.search(/'csrf'/i);
var dataBeforeCsrf = htmlData.slice(0, csrfIndex);

//remove content before csrf node
htmlData = htmlData.replace(dataBeforeCsrf, '');

//to make it in right format of JSON, replace single quote with double, 
//remove ; and add bracket

htmlData = htmlData.replace(/'/g, '"');
htmlData = htmlData.replace(';', '');

//parse to JSON 
var jsonData = JSON.parse('{' + htmlData);

//print csrf
console.log(jsonData.csrf);
```

[image]

Comment: That is something different than your original question. I can show you a way of doing it. But cannot code for you. You have to find the required element by adding console logs, there is no another way.